# Compiler error with custom comparator function as template argument

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I can't get the Heap class to accept the Comparator as the second template argument. The compiler keeps trying to instantiate a Comparator object. Why? All I want is a comparision between the 2 provided inputs. Here's the compiler error:

```
  In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Heap.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void Heap<T, Cmp>::bubbleUp(size_t) [with T = long unsigned int; Cmp = Comparator<long unsigned int>; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
Heap.hpp:29:35:   required from ‘void Heap<T, Cmp>::insert(const T&) [with T = long unsigned int; Cmp = Comparator<long unsigned int>]’
main.cpp:7:15:   required from here
Heap.hpp:119:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘Comparator<long unsigned int>::Comparator(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<long unsigned int> >::value_type&, __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<long unsigned int> >::value_type&)’
         if (Cmp(fArray[idx], fArray[getParent(idx)]))
         ^
Heap.hpp:119:9: note: candidates are:
Heap.hpp:128:7: note: constexpr Comparator<long unsigned int>::Comparator()
 class Comparator
```

Here's the class

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <assert.h>
#include "boost/optional.hpp"

template <typename T, typename Cmp>
class Heap
{

  public:
    Heap()
        : fArray()
    {
    }
    ~Heap() {}
    void insert(const T &toInsert)
    {
        fArray.push_back(toInsert);
        bubbleUp(fArray.size() - 1);
    }


  private:
    std::vector<T> fArray;
    size_t getParent(size_t i) const
    {
        assert(i / 2 < fArray.size());
        return i / 2;
    } 


    void bubbleUp(size_t idx)
    {
        if (idx == 0)
        {
            return;
            // return early if root
        }
        // If heap property violated, swap and recurse upwards
        if (Cmp(fArray[idx], fArray[getParent(idx)])
        {
            std::iter_swap(fArray.begin() + idx, fArray.begin() + getParent(idx));
            bubbleUp(getParent(idx));
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the comparator:

```
template <typename T>
class Comparator
{
  public:
    bool operator()(const T &o1, const T &&o2)
    {
        return o1 < o2;
    }
};
```

Here's the main function

```
int main(){
    Heap< size_t,Comparator<size_t> >  h;
    h.insert(4);
    h.insert(5);
    h.insert(6);
    h.insert(3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking your comparator here:

```
if (Cmp(fArray[idx], fArray[getParent(idx)])
```

`Cmp` is your comparator class. This is the template parameter, which you specify as your `Comparator` template instance.

Now, set aside the topic of templates, for the moment. For all practical purposes, `Cmp` is a class here. Pretend it's an ordinary, plain class:

```
class Cmp {

 // ...
};
```

Now, ask yourself, what would expression:

```
Cmp(fArray[idx], fArray[getParent(idx)])
```

mean, then?

It means, of course: construct a temporary instance of the `Cmp` class, and pass two parameters to `Cmp`'s constructor.

Now, you should be able to understand your problem. Your comparator class does not have a constructor that takes two parameters. That's what your compiler is telling you.

Your comparator class has an overloaded `()` operator, instead.

It makes no sense to construct a temporary object, in your use case. Your obvious intent here is to model your `Heap` template and use it in a similar way to how the standard C++ library's containers use comparator classes.

What the standard C++ library's containers actually do, loosely speaking, is that they declare a class member that's an instance of the comparator class, and then invoke the class member's `()` operator overload.

This loosely translates into your `Heap` template declaring a private class member:

```
private:
    Cmp cmp;
```

And then invoking this class member's `()` operator overload.

```
if (cmp(fArray[idx], fArray[getParent(idx)])
```

Also, note that standard C++ library containers typically have an overloaded constructor that takes an explicit instance of the comparator class, and then uses it to copy-construct their private comparator instance.